# Multithread Socket in Python, Message Error UniUnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, http, tcp

## UniUnicodeDecodeError (While Sending Message to Client)

I'm implementing a server/client socket in python, and the following code **sometimes** raise the UniUnicodeDecodeError exception. I don't know why sometimes works and sometimes not. Please help...

---

### **Server**

```
conn.sendall('200 OK'.encode('utf-8'))
while l:
    self.conn.sendall(l)
    l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not l:
         f.close()
         self.conn.close()
         break
```

### **Client**

```
HTTP_RCV_CODE = tcp_sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
HTTP_RCV_CODE = HTTP_RCV_CODE.decode('utf-8')
```

---

#### When Works

> Server answer: 200 OK Connection close.

#### UniUnicodeDecodeError

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "navegador.py", line 40, in
>   
>       HTTP_RCV_CODE = HTTP_RCV_CODE.decode('utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 49: invalid start
>   byte

---

### [Solution]

Just adding a time delay solve my problem, apparently the server was sending the 200 OK message and some parts of the file together.

### **Server**

```
conn.sendall('200 OK'.encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(0.1)

while l:
    self.conn.sendall(l)
    l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not l:
         f.close()
         self.conn.close()
         break
```

Comment: Seeing the actual content of `HTTP_RCV_CODE` that is being decoded would help.

Comment: @MarkTolonen When occurs the error the message is:
HTTP_RCV_CODE = b'200 OK\x00\x00\x00 ...
But, i don't know why sometimes the server send correctly and sometimes send this message above.

Comment: Edit your question to show the *entire* buffer content being decoded.  There is no `\x9b` in your partial example.  Also, those nulls in the data indicate the data received is not entirely UTF-8, but contains binary data, so it looks like assuming the data is UTF-8-encoded is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for the help, i've postted the solution above... :)

Comment: A time delay isn't the real solution.  TCP is just a stream of bytes.  You have to follow a protocol.  It's like writing to a file without ever sending newlines.  How do you read a line of a file without newlines?  In the HTTP protocol `\r\n` terminates a line of the response.  You buffer the read and extract a line of data by looking for the `\r\n` in the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding.  TCP is not a message protocol but a streaming protocol, so `recv` can return bytes that break apart a complete UTF-8 multibyte character.

In your case, though, the byte received is a UTF-8 intermediate byte (it cannot occur as the first byte of a multibyte sequence), but it occurs in the middle/end of your received buffer, so it looks like it isn't valid UTF-8.  If a valid UTF-8 character was broken, you should get `invalid start byte` if it is at the beginning of your buffer, and `unexpected end of data` at the end of the buffer.